# Need shell script to compare files

Tags: shell, unix

I want to pick one line at a time  of a file(file1.txt) and compare with all the lines of another file(file2.txt) and check whether is there any entry for that line or not.

I have two files(file1.txt and file2.txt)
and also file names which are presented in the files also present in the directory gdir/db/files.

```
file1.txt

/db/day_files/data_feed20161231
/db/day_files/data_feed20161229
/db/day_files/data_feed20161125
/db/day_files/data_feed20161118

file2.txt
data_feed20161229
data_feed20161125
```

Req1 : First we have to check whether the file1.txt and file2.txt files are presented in the directory gdir/db/files or not.
If any of the file is not existed just display the message file1.txt is not existed 
(or) file2.txt is not existed (or) file1.txt and file2.txt are not existed.

Req2:Read the file names from file1.txt(one line ata a time) 
and compare it against all(all the lines) the names present in the file2.txt file in a loop. 
And that loop will run checking one file name at a time.

a.  If the file name  matches, will move that file to a path gdir/old/files and return value 10 to a variable and will keep running if more file names exist.
b.  If the file name  does not match in the list it will return value 20 and continue with other.

Please help me.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: use linux `diff` command. like - `diff file1.txt file2.txt`

Answer (score 0):

```
while read line; do
    if grep -Fxq "$line" file-where-search.txt
    then
        # code if found
    else
        # code if not found
    fi
done <file-source.txt
```

To add path to filename use string:

```
"/path/to/file/$line"
```

To remove path and take only filename use

```
filename=`basename "/path/to/file/filename.ext"`
```